# How to solve $\int \frac{\mathrm dx}{3x^2-7}$?

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals, fractions, substitution

Do not know why but the integral drovw mw crazy
$$\int \frac{\mathrm dx}{3x^2-7}$$

I tried $$\int(3x^2-7)^{-1}\,\mathrm dx$$ and then apply Chebyshev’s criterion, but it did not work :/

Comment: [Integrating any rational function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition#Application_to_symbolic_integration)

Comment: It's like $\int \frac{du}{u^2-a^2}=\int \frac{du}{(u-a)(u+a)}$ let -a=b and use: $\int \frac{du}{(u+b)(u+a)}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this substitution: $x=\dfrac{\sqrt{7}}{\sqrt{3}}\sin u$ so $\mathrm dx= \dfrac{\sqrt{7}}{\sqrt{3}}\cos u$ and we have:

$$\int \dfrac{\frac{\sqrt{7}}{\sqrt{3}}\cos u}{7\cos^{2}u}\,\mathrm du=\frac{\sqrt{7}}{7\sqrt{3}}\int \sec u\,\mathrm du$$

which is easy to find.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Just express $\dfrac1{3x^2-7}$ as$$\frac13\left(\frac a{x-\sqrt{\frac73}}+\frac b{x+\sqrt{\frac73}}\right).$$

Comment: its $\frac 73$ .....at the denominator

Comment: @Isham I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use partial fractions

$$\int\dfrac{dx}{(\sqrt{3}x-\sqrt{7})(\sqrt{3}x+\sqrt{7})}=a\int\dfrac{dx}{\sqrt{3}x-\sqrt{7}}+b\int\dfrac{dx}{\sqrt{3}x+\sqrt{7}}$$

In which the coefficients can be directly determined by Euler's trick:

$$a=\left.\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}x+\sqrt{7}}\right|_{x=\dfrac{\sqrt{7}}{\sqrt{3}}}$$
$$b=\left.\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}x-\sqrt{7}}\right|_{x=-\dfrac{\sqrt{7}}{\sqrt{3}}}.$$